# Is it worth implementing Entity Framework when calling a single stored select?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently building a web application for my enterprise level business internship. This web application will track data from three different sources: a DB2 database, a SQL Dynamic database, and an existing API, and then marry them together.

I'm currently working on the SQL Dynamic side, and I was advised to use Entity Framework to streamline this process. From what I understand, EF is useful when creating local database contexts to perform queries against, generating SQL code, and when updating/inserting records to provide security and performance benefit. However, the SQL data that I need to marry will only be provided by a SELECT, and will be implementing a single stored procedure that will return the data I need.

I have already developed an API to access SQL stored procedures in C# (I was advised this would help them and myself greatly due to their DB infrastructure). I personally don't see the benefit of adding Entity Framework to this solution; in my view (which, take with a grain of salt as a result of my intern position), adding EF to this solution will only increase dependency on non-internal packages and increase complexity of maintenance in the future. I don't need to generate SQL code, and I don't need to insert records; I just need to pass parameters.

In a scenario like this, where I am passing parameters to a single stored procedure already housed in the SQL DB I'm accessing, where can Entity Framework benefit me? If it won't, are there any more convincing reasons I can provide to those above me to remove this dependency?

Comment: I'd agree on your reasons *against* EF, given the little I know about your requirements Some of the advantages of EF are in the way it can scale and 'migrate' data and schema changes, doesn't sound like you need to leverage that.

Comment: In terms of convincing reasons, I'd always want to justify reasons *for* introducing a technology rather than against. They're the ones who proposed the introduction of EF, so...why? What does 'streamline' mean? I assume they mean it's easy to set-up, but that's about it. Consider, though, you may still need an ORM (possibly look at dapper).

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I agree with this train of thought. I'm not entirely sure if I will need an ORM; the API I made converts results from each DB into standard .NET supported types, to make future marriage compatible. I don't, however, know if my application could be further benefited by ORM, and I will do some research. If that's the case, EF will likely be my only option due to policy.

Comment: EF provides very simple mechanisms for calling stored procedures.  Your reasoning suggests that your philosophy for data access is "all stored procedures, all the time," a valid but controversial opinion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't actually think this, really; I just haven't worked with EF, but have been working with a stored procedure based data infrastructure for a while now. It appears that we are moving towards EF for some reason, and I'd like to understand if this would benefit my use-case at all. I'm happy to use other solutions, I just need some convincing is all; I love being convinced of new ways to do things I have imagined or implemented.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I will do more research on calling existing stored procedures using EF, I had gotten the wrong impression on my first search of it and as such was prompted to ask here.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: I just wanted to commend you for respectfully questioning the wisdom of your seniors. You may want to just directly ask them why they feel it’s worthwhile to add EF. Maybe they feel like the project will grow and want to set a pattern now. When in doubt, have a conversation. Software is 80% having conversations with customers & peers in my experience.

Comment: Have you considered that after your internship ends, they will be maintaining this app and perhaps they will need to add more to it in the future such that it's easier if you user ef up front before it's really needed rather then rewriting what you've done?  Or perhaps they are giving you a chance to learn with something simple, learning being the point of your internship?

Comment: @Andy I don't believe this app will be expanding beyond selecting data, and due to the environment surrounding it, it would require a full code rewrite or a drastic change in design in order to implement EF. I did end up talking to my superiors, and they agreed; I had mostly posted this here for further insight on the benefits and use cases of EF in this sort of situation. Thank you for the insight though!

Answer (score 1):

No. Its not worth adding EF if you are comfortable with SqlClient for your needs.

Although you can call sprocs and run your own SQL strings via EF easily enough, its not leveraging its features and it has a few quirks to trap the unwarey, which may trip you up.

In fact its arguable that its never worth adding EF. But lets leave that for another day.

Answer (score 1):

EF can certainly feel a little heavy at times. Since you are comfortable with writing SQL maybe a micro ORM like Dapper suits your needs better.